# Which groups of a given order have the "most complicated" structure?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.

The size of the group $G/[G,G]$ is a measure of "how abelian" the group is. The larger the size of this group, "the more abelian" it is.

> Is there some similar measure for "how complicated" the structure of a given group is ?

The easiest ones are intuitively the cyclic groups followed by the abelian groups. Then, we should have groups being direct products of non-trivial groups.

The number of generators is not useful because elementar abelian groups have "many" generators, but are not "complicated".

I am not sure whether the following definition is suitable, but to avoid the question being too broad I suggest :

The complexity of a group is defined by the ratio $\large \frac{number\ of \ non-commutating\ pairs}{maximum\ of\ the \ element-orders}$. The larger the complexity, the "more complicated" the group is.

Comment: This feels like a way too broad/unfocused question, unless you can provide a more precise meaning to being complicated.

Comment: Also, the size of $G/G'$ is not necessarily the best (or at least the only) measure of how abelian a group is. The measure of commutativity is an alternative.

Comment: Hmm, my immediate instinct would be something like the ratio of the number of relations to generators (when this quotient is as small as possible).

Comment: This sounds good! But can the minimum of this quotient be calculated efficiently, for example with GAP ?

Comment: No idea, it was just the first thing that came to mind, and I have never seen it considered anywhere.

Comment: I think this is too unfocused of a question. Groups can be complicated in many ways, and which way is relevant depends on what you want to do. Ask something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is very broad, let me give a comment on the first question, "how abelian is a group". This can be already quite complicated, in the sense of the results of Erdös, Straus and Pyber (Reference: 
Pyber, L.: How abelian is a finite group?)

[*Theorem:*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-60408-9_27)  Every group of order $n$ contains an abelian subgroup of order at least
$2^{\epsilon \sqrt{\log (n)}}$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

We could associate to a finite group the maximal order of an abelian subgroup. Now this does not answer what we understand of having the "most complicated" structure, but the maximal dimension of a subgroup having property $P$ might say something about how complicated a group is.

Comment: Is a concrete $\epsilon$ known for which the claim is true for all $n$ ?

Comment: I think, Erdös and Straus gave an explicit value (I have no access to their paper).